# Цена на лосось

Tags: склонение

"Рыбный" вопрос! Из сегодняшних новостей :

> Группа компаний «Русское море» увеличила отпускную **цену на охлажденный лосось** в два раза на фоне введения эмбарго на поставки рыбы.

В данном контексте, очевидно, под торговым термином *лосось* подразумевается *мясо лосося*, то есть *лососина*. И поэтому при склонении в В.п. наш *лосось* - неодушевлен. Но почему тогда он является одушевленным в других подобных случаях?

> Людмила Лопато. Волшебное зеркало воспоминаний (2002-2003)
> Я пробовал некоторые закуски ― и, поверьте, впредь **буду заказывать не копченого лосося** из Норвегии, а красную икру со сливками, копченого угря, паштет из лосося и, конечно, свежую икру.
>
> Андрей Дмитриев. Закрытая книга (1999)
> Вы, однако, своего добились, ― сказал он Маарет, **доедая копченого лосося**.

После покупки в магазине "неживой" охлажденный лосось чудесным образом "оживает" на нашей сковороде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вы правильно заметили , в первом предложении под торговым термином лосось подразумевается мясо лосося, то есть лососина. Поэтому винительный падеж. Надо однако заметить , что названия животных относятся к одушевленным существительным. Во втором примере подразумевается не столько само  мясо э, как само животное. Отсюда и родительный падеж.

***Дополнение***

***Цитата из учебника "Современный русский язык" (авт. Валгина Н. С, Розенталь Д. Э, Фомина М. И. ) :***
"Названия рыб и амфибий в собственном значении являются именами существительными одушевленными (ловить омаров, килек) , но те же слова как названия блюд чаще всего имеют форму винительного падежа, совпадающую с именительным (более характерно для разговорной речи) ".

Comment: То есть логика такая : в магазине их, лососей, много... а едим мы конкретного, своего лосося.  
>Павел Санаев. Похороните меня за плинтусом (1995)  
Лосося… Сейчас такого лосося дам, что забудешь, кто ты есть!

Comment: Спасибо за ценное и квалифицированное дополнение к ответу, Серж.

Answer (score 1):

Я не согласен с такой формой.

Да, "лосось" в значении собирательного существительного и/или как кушанье не имеет множественного числа - этим и отличается от "штучного" лосося. 
И В исходной фразе имеется в виду явно такое "собирательное" значение, т.е. желание сделать объект неодушевленным понятно, поскольку по относительно недавним правилам такие слова не могли быть грамматически одушевлены. Видимо, так посчитал и автор (редактор?) текста.

Но в современном языке подобные слова вполне могут быть одушевленными:  *добывать камчатского краба, разводить соболя, ловить омуля, охотиться на моржа* - эти формы почти безальтернативны.

Поэтому я и в исходном примере использовал бы одушевленную форму: *цена на охлажденного лосося*.  Путаницы возникнуть не должно.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно то, что чаще покупают "лосося", но цены практически всегда "на лосось" и даже "на краб".

ПРИМЕРЫ

При этом уровне сдаточной цены предполагаемая цена ФОБ на краб рассольной заморозки составит более $12/фунт.

На сайте вы можете узнать, где купить лосося в Москве,

Если вы искали, где можно купить лосось по более чем лояльной стоимости, вы попали на нужную страницу.

Answer (score 1):

Немного не по теме. Падеж в любом случае винительный: цена на кого/что. Если лосось одушевленный - на лосося, если нет - на лосось.

Comment: Да, в принятом ответе есть небольшая неточность. Форма В.п. совпадает с формой Р.п. при одушевленности предмета.

Comment: @Innak, Вы совершенно верно заметили. Но никто и не утверждал обратного. Дерзкий Grantum именно об этом и пишет.

Answer (score 0):

Парадигма Зализняка предлагает только один вариант: В.п. *лосося*. Грамота.ру пишет, что такой вариант предпочтителен.

Comment: Да, вот и статья. http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_463861

Comment: Увы, действительность не всегда согласуется с мнением Зализняка. Покупать надо "лосося", но ставить ценник на одушевленный предмет просто неприлично, вот что не было учтено наукой. Поэтому и пишется: "цена на лосось".

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен! Еще два века назад, когда не было правил Зализника,  в самом начале развития языка названия рыб испытывали колебания, но Зализняк это , видимо, не учел, или просто закрыл глаза. Потом найду ссылку на примеры.