# "Укладываем лосося" или "укладываем лосось"?

Tags: склонение, падежи

Разгорелся нешуточный спор, как правильно - "укладываем охлажденный лосось" или "укладываем охлаждённого лосося". Для меня очевиден второй вариант, но 99% опрошенных настаивают на правильности первого. Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Копоть, сажу смыл под душем, съел холодного язя,— и инструктора прослушал — что там можно, что нельзя. (В.В.)

Comment: Как математик, не могу не заметить: чтобы получить 99%, нужно опросить как минимум 67 человек ( 66 из 67 = 98.51%, округленно 99%;  но 65 из 66 = 98.48%, округленно 98%)

Comment: Эти участники опроса пробовали "укладывать осётр"?

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос о падеже, то ответ простой: винительный. Но суть не в падеже, а в одушевленности предмета (отвечат на вопрос кого? или что?). Лосося можно рассматривать как существо или как пищу (блюдо). Исходя из этого получаем два разных ответа.

Вот оба варианта в примерах из Нацкорпуса:

> Филе рыбы обжариваем (можно **использовать готовый лосось** в собственном соку), разминаем, смешиваем с нарезанным зеленым луком и петрушкой. [Дарья ЗАВГОРОДНЯЯ.. Кулебяка от Гоголя и салат от Бунина // Комсомольская правда, 2005.04.21]
>
> Перевозчикам невыгодно работать с рыбаками, потому что они в основном **возят лосось** (остальные виды рыбы в большинстве своем уходят на экспорт или на прибрежные перерабатывающие предприятия). [Кира Ремнева. Закусили удила // «Однако», 2009]
>
> Чтобы товар не пропал, рыбакам нередко приходилось избавляться от рыбы в максимально короткие сроки, **продавая лосось** чуть ли не по 5 рублей за килограмм китайцам или корейцам. [Кира Ремнева. Закусили удила // «Однако», 2009]

---

> Он **коптит балтийского лосося** и продает его поштучно отдыхающим в поселке и в пансионатах. [Андрей Дмитриев. Штиль (1983)]
>
> За несколько дней до бала мы начнем **готовить копченого лосося** и пельмени. [Галя Галкина. Вольфганг Пак: «Для перекуса мы сделаем лососевые «Оскары» // Известия, 2013.02.19]
>
> Чтобы выжить в холодных водах, они начали приобретать навыки «генетического хакерства» и научились **использовать тихоокеанских лососей** для вынашивания личинок. [Д. Фащук. «Дело пестрых» // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]  [омонимия не снята]

Дополнение. Грамота считает предпочтительным употребление слова *[лосось](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C&start=15)* как одушевленного существительного:

> Существительные мужского рода – названия рыб (лосось, осетр, лещ, карась и т. д.), как правило, употребляются как одушевленные существительные.
>
> Проясняем. Лосось, по "Грамматическому словарю русского языка" А. А. Зализняка, всегда одушевленное существительное, в том числе и в значении "пища".
>
> Правильно: *лосося* (*порезать мелкими кусочками* - М_Г).
>
> Предпочтительно: *заказали лосося*.

Answer (score 1):

Купить дикий/охлажденный/замороженный  **лосось**, выгодные цены на **лосось**  – это обычные объявления, вариант "лосося" встречается, но значительно реже.

Таким образом, в торговле и  промысловом деле лосось обычно рассматривается как **предмет неодушевленный.** Но ловля лосося – Р.п. для одушевленного существительного.

А в общем случае действует правило Розенталя, где также указывается на возможность вариантов (см. [§153. Формы винительного падежа одушевленных и неодушевленных существительных](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_08)):

> В различии форм поймал трех рыбок – съел три рыбки сказывается то обстоятельство, что во втором случае имеется в виду кушанье, т.е. неодушевленность (ср.: съесть кильки, сардины, шпроты – как нерасчлененный продукт; но: съесть карасей, раков, цыплят – как единичные предметы). Возможные варианты: есть креветок, устриц, пулярок – есть креветки, устрицы, пулярки.

См. также: [Цена на лосось](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37276/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C/37366)

Comment: Я бы из "креветок с устрицами" не вывел, что Розенталь готов был есть "лосось" или "осётр". "Цены на осётр" тоже встречается у оптовиков?

Comment: Розенталь рассказал нам о существовании вариантов, назвал возможные факторы, влияющие на выбор, но на этом его прямое руководство в теме, я думаю, закончилось.  Дальше  выбираем сами с учетом здравого смысла, традиций употребления в разных ситуациях, фонетических особенностей слов и др.

Answer (score 0):

Если рассматривать охлажденного лосося как одушевленный объект, то второй вариант правильный:

> укладываем (кого?) охлажденного лосося

Если же рассматривать охлажденный лосось как неодушевленный объект, то первый вариант правильный.

> укладываем (что?) охлажденный лосось

Answer (score 0):

Да, вопрос в одушевленности, не в падеже.

Тут говорилось о двух значениях слова лосось (именно у единственного числа) два значения. Это не совсем правильно.
Значений или одно (по Кузнецову, например) - или три.
1. Рыба - в штучном измерении.
2. Блюдо из лосося, пища.
3. Мясо лосося, лососина (что оно такое есть можно убедится по вывескам типа "торговля лососем").

Так вот, в первом случае лосось одушевлен. Во втором испытывает колебания (как, например, "краб" - "есть крабы" или "есть крабов"?), но в современном языке тяготеет к одушевленному, поэтому "Грамота", если она действительно сказала такое, права.

К сожалению, второе и третье значение часто смешивают. Отсюда недоразумения.
Сравним два примера от М_Г

Первый.

> Филе рыбы обжариваем (можно использовать **готовый лосось** в собственном
>   соку), разминаем, смешиваем с нарезанным зеленым луком и петрушкой.
>   [Дарья ЗАВГОРОДНЯЯ.. Кулебяка от Гоголя и салат от Бунина //
>   Комсомольская правда, 2005.04.21]

Здесь ошибка, Лосось здесь пища, блюдо. Замена на "лососина" не прходит по смыслу. Поэтому "использовать готового лосося", вариант "готовый лосось" как минимум устарел.

Второй

> Перевозчикам невыгодно работать с рыбаками, потому что они в основном
>   **возят лосось** (остальные виды рыбы в большинстве своем уходят на
>   экспорт или на прибрежные перерабатывающие предприятия). [Кира
>   Ремнева. Закусили удила // «Однако», 2009]

А Вот тут правильно. Речь о ***лососине***. Это собирательное значение. Как "рыба", "мясо" или "яйцо" - в магазине или на рынке. В таком собирательно-обобщающем значении слова эти не бывают одушевленными (по крайней мере я не знаю убедительных примеров обратного).

//===

Спрашивается, откуда же во вполне приличные тексты залезает лосось в неодушевленном варианте - туда, где это никак невозможно?!
Все просто до банальности. Лосось до самого недавнего времени испытывал колебание в грамматическом роде (а заодно и в месте ударения).
Поэтому обороты "купил (копченую) л**о**сось" совсем не случайны, просто это что-то рудиментарное.